# Using pathlib.Path, how to efficiently check if a directory resides anywhere under another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I prefer to work mainly with `pathlib.Path`s. However, in the following example code, I ended up comparing strings like this:

```
if str(dir2).startswith(str(dir1))
```

`dir1` and `dir2` are `Path`s. Is there a better way to find out if `dir2` is an arbitrarily nested subdirectory of `dir1`?

```
from pathlib import Path

mydirs = [Path('/a/a/a/a'), Path('/a/a/'), Path('/a/b/'), Path('/a/a/b'), Path('/b/a/a/'), Path('/a/a/a/a/a/a/'), Path('/a/b/a/a/a/')]

mydirs.sort(key = lambda x: len(x.parts))
roots = mydirs.copy()

for dir1 in mydirs:
    for dir2 in mydirs:
        if dir1 == dir2 or len(dir2.parts) <= len(dir1.parts):
            continue
        if str(dir2).startswith(str(dir1)):
            roots.remove(dir2)
            print(f'pruned subdir {str(dir2)} of {str(dir1)}')

print(roots)
```

Comment: How are you measuring "better"?

Comment: You can do `str(dir1) in dir2.parts`

Comment: You're asking for "efficiently". Do you have a huge number of paths? Then perhaps the how-to-check-dir1-vs-dir2 check is a red herring and you should use a whole different algorithm rather than this quadratic one.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - yes, I have a huge number of paths. What "whole different algorithm" do you suggest?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: I selected an answer, but if you provide an answer with a more efficient algorithm, I'll accept it.

Comment: Probably something like sorting lexicographically and just checking each dir against the previous dir, or using sorting by length and and keeping a set of already seen paths.

Comment: Ok, added one to my answer. Only tested with your small example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
str(dir2).startswith(str(dir1))
```

try

```
dir1 in dir2.parents
```

---

If you have many paths, you probably shouldn't try all pairs. Here's a set solution:

```
mydirs.sort(key=lambda dir: len(dir.parts))
roots = set()
for dir in mydirs:
    if roots.isdisjoint(dir.parents):
        roots.add(dir)
```

---

Btw, your solution is buggy, as you're incorrectly removing from a list while iterating it. For example for

```
mydirs = [Path('/a/'), Path('/a/a/'), Path('/a/b/')]
```

you only prune `'/a/a/'` but keep `'/a/b/'`.

Comment: @MountainX Ah, just realized you're not necessarily testing all pairs, since you're filtering on the go. You're doing it wrong, btw. For example your solution [fails](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsQgEIbvPMXcConppnoxG/sO3o0HuoUssTBkoLqN2WevUNiqOyf@f@b7B/BLPKN7eva0rprQgpfxPJkBjPVIEV6TZMwuo6EAPbxlzZuDPDTiAXZxJ4ck329UG1IO/1BLwidph1HC5QiTcvzSekkxCMEIMeb4SpzQL1wwppEgGR0YV1tHBqmq/5j9DS12LqML0fdlIk3mVflct8FLf7O6av3iuU7oonGz@psZIm0Zog0xI18mPbWanbgL2K7UkrL4qQr1r@3JuMh142l2aoQwD2kGvvcVV0C9y05cm/QThdmCxbr@AA) for `mydirs = [Path('/a/'), Path('/a/a/'), Path('/a/b/')]`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the problem with my solution. Your solution works correctly on `[Path('/a/'), Path('/a/a/'), Path('/a/b/')]`. I will be doing more testing.

Comment: I will edit my question to fix that issue, btw.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [`is_relative_to()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to):

```
if dir2.is_relative_to(dir1):
    # Do something
```

Depending on your exact use case you might find it helpful to [`resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) one or both of the `Path`s:

```
if dir2.resolve().is_relative_to(dir1.resolve())
```

This should ensure that something like `/foo/../bar/baz` is seen as relative to `/quux/../bar`.

Note that `is_relative_to()` was introduced in Python 3.9.